# Converting input into nicely formatted numbers (javascript)

Tags: javascript, rounding

Two part question.

Part 1 is easy, but I'm wondering what you think is the most elegant solution:

What would be the best procedure to use to convert input into cleanly formatted and WITH "normal" comma placement.  The input could range from:

- $8000
- 8200
- 8,000.50

And I want it to output simply: 8,000

Part 2, may be easy I just don't know the right operation.  I want to round numbers so that: it is rounded based on the number of digits. So that there are TWO unrounded digits at all time.

- 45,643 should be 46,000
- 453 should be 450
- 59,023,920 should be 59,000,000

Comment: Why is this a bad question? 1. Ask one question at a time. 2. Show some code (minimal effort). 3. Make your requirements clearly defined.

Comment: The second part is not logic, you round numbers with decimal part, but in those examples are integer numbers (with thousands separator)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should answer both parts of the question:

```
var input = "$820322310";               // String input
input = input.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ""); // remove all unnecessary characters
input = input.replace(/\.[0-9]+/, "");  // remove all after decimal (convert to integer)
if(parseInt(input[2]) >= 5) {           // rounding to two decimal places
    input[1] = input.slice(0, 1) + (parseInt(input[1]) + 1) + input.slice(2, input.length);
}
var count = 0;
for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(i > 2) {
        input = input.slice(0, i-1) + "0" + input.slice(i, input.length);
    }
    if(++count == 3 && i != 0) {
        count = 0;
        input = input.slice(0, i) + "," + input.slice(i, input.length);
    }
}
```

See this at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k61ojoru/1/).